# How can I add an specific row into database from another database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to pass a specific row from database to another database by clicking the add button. my dbconnection is included at the top of it.

[Here is the my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL3g7.png)

Here is my Code

```
<table style="margin-left: 28%;">
  <tr>
     <th><h2>Product Code</h2></th>
     <th><h2>Products and Services</h2></th>
     <th><h2>Amount</h2></th>
     <th><h2>Action</h2></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <?php
    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM products_and_services";
    $select_result = mysqli_query($connection,$select_query);
  ?>

  <?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($select_result)):; 
    $id = $rows[0];
    $prod_code = $rows[1];
    $service = $rows[2];
    $amount = $rows[3];
  ?>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rows[1]; ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rows[2]; ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $rows[3]; ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="" name="add">Add</td>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
      $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_table (Product_name,Product_price,Product_ID) 
      VALUES ('$service','$amount','$id')";
      mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    }
  ?>
 </tr>
  <?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: `<?php while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($select_result)):;` <<< you see that? it ended your loop.

Comment: You're also using the wrong db connection for one of those.

Comment: my db connection is okay. it displays all the items inside a database table. all the items in the table is all selected from db

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection` <<< `mysqli_query($db` <<< different. So.... which one is successful?

Comment: `<a href="" name="add">Add` << are you relying on that for `$_POST['add']`? your question's way too unclear for me. Sorry, but I'll have to pass on this one.